# How to call the shipping method click event on custom dropdown click event in magento 2?

Tags: custom-options, shipping-methods, magento2.4.4

I have a dropdown to choose store for pickups after select the custom shipping methods **Store Pickup**.

I want to call the **shipping method** click event on **change function** in the pickup store dropdown again.

How to call the shipping method click event here? My checkout interface is looks like below.

[image]

Update( shipping-option-select.js )

```
hasChanged: function () {
        var notEqual = this.value() !== this.initialValue;

        let store_id = this.value._latestValue;
        let currentcomponent = self;


        $.ajax({
            url:storepickupurl,
            type: 'POST',
            async:false,
            data: { 'id' : store_id },
            success:function (data) {
                currentcomponent.changeStoreInfoObj(data);
                let checkoutData = customerData.get('checkout-data')();
                //alert(data);
                $('.shipping-store-block').css('display','block');

                currentcomponent.storeAddress({
                    name: data.store_name,
                    store_email: data.store_email,
                    store_address: data.store_address1,
                    store_city: data.store_city,
                    store_zipcode: data.store_zipcode,
                    store_state: data.store_state,
                    store_country: data.store_country,
                    store_telephone: data.store_telephone
                });
                currentcomponent.isVisibleStoreInformation(true);
                
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log("There has been an error retrieving the values from the database.");
            }
        });
        console.log(self.storeAddress().name);

        return !this.visible() ? false : notEqual;
    },
```

Template File

```
<div class="additional-shipping-option-wrapper" data-bind="visible: showAdditionalOption()" style="display: none;">
<div class="step-title" data-role="title" data-bind="i18n: 'Choose Store'"></div>
<!-- ko foreach: element.getRegion('additionalShippingOptionField') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: are you using Magento's default store pickup or any third party extension?

Comment: It's  a custom module written by myself, Since in this project scope No MSI involving.

Comment: Can you please add your template code for pickup store and js file code bind with the template?

Comment: @TarunBhalodia i. ave updated the js and template files contents, On Js i updated only. the change event section.

Comment: @Mujahidh have you used MageWorx Delivery date module?

Comment: @Msquare no i am not used it here.

Comment: I have updated my answer please refer it now.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below code

Inject
**Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method**
**underscore**, **'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method'**, **'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data'**, **'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service'**, **'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address'**
as below in your js

```
define([
    ....
    ....
    underscore,
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    ....
    ....

], function (
    ....
    ....
    _,
    selectShippingMethodAction,
    checkoutData,
    shippingService,
    selectShippingAddress,
    ....
    ....
) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            rate: {
                'carrier_code': 'carrierCode', // Set your carrier code here
                'method_code': 'methodCode' // Set your method code here
            },
            rates: shippingService.getShippingRates()
        },
        hasChanged: function () {
            var notEqual = this.value() !== this.initialValue;

            let store_id = this.value._latestValue;
            let currentcomponent = self;


            $.ajax({
                url:storepickupurl,
                type: 'POST',
                async:false,
                data: { 'id' : store_id },
                success:function (data) {
                    currentcomponent.changeStoreInfoObj(data);
                    let checkoutData = customerData.get('checkout-data')();
                    //alert(data);
                    $('.shipping-store-block').css('display','block');

                    currentcomponent.storeAddress({
                        name: data.store_name,
                        store_email: data.store_email,
                        store_address: data.store_address1,
                        store_city: data.store_city,
                        store_zipcode: data.store_zipcode,
                        store_state: data.store_state,
                        store_country: data.store_country,
                        store_telephone: data.store_telephone
                    });
                    currentcomponent.isVisibleStoreInformation(true);
                    
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log("There has been an error retrieving the values from the database.");
                }
            });
            console.log(self.storeAddress().name);
            this.selectStorePickupShippingMethod(); // Here you will select the store pick up shipping method

            return !this.visible() ? false : notEqual;
        },
        selectStorePickupShippingMethod: function () {
            var pickupShippingMethod = _.findWhere(
                this.rates(),
                {
                    'carrier_code': this.rate['carrier_code'],
                    'method_code': this.rate['method_code']
                },
                this
            );

            this.selectShippingMethod(pickupShippingMethod);
        },
        selectShippingMethod: function (shippingMethod) {
            selectShippingMethodAction(shippingMethod);
            checkoutData.setSelectedShippingRate(
                shippingMethod ? shippingMethod['carrier_code'] + '_' + shippingMethod['method_code'] : null
            );
        }
    });
});
```

**Don't forget to add **carrierCode** and **methodCode** in js file.**

**If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.**

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have tried in a different way. I will upload that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected shipping method value in js so on that based you can show your dropdown.

File: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js

```
selectShippingMethod: function (shippingMethod) {
    console.log(shippingMethod['carrier_code']);
    selectShippingMethodAction(shippingMethod);
    checkoutData.setSelectedShippingRate(shippingMethod['carrier_code'] + '_' + shippingMethod['method_code']);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks For the reply, Actually i need to recall the shipping save method during the on change of the store drop down

Answer (score 0):

Inject `'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor'` to the **shipping-option-select.js** file and call **saveShippingInformation();** method in hasChanged function.

```
define([
...
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor'
], function (
...
shippingSave
) {
'use strict'; 
...
    hasChanged: function () { 
      ...
      shippingSave.saveShippingInformation();
      ...
    },    
 });
});
```

This part did the trick for me after many strugling.